# How Can I Set Permissions On A folder An All Content VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Under the Startup Path of my App I have a folder called BatFiles which contains some .bat files

On the App interface, I have buttons which when pressed will write to and run a specific bat file in the BatFiles Folder.

Under development, this works fine but after the app has been installed using a setup installer, the BatFiles Folder is ReadOnly so the program throws an error.

Ive been scratching my head for a few days on this and the only answer I can think of is to make the BatFiles folder have full permissions when the app starts but I cannot think how to achieve this in VB.Net

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Read permissions is what you need to run a file.

Comment: Read permissions and Not Change permissions ?

Comment: Yes. Read permissions and not change permissions.

Comment: "... write to and run a specific bat file ..."  So you are creating the bat file at runtime before running it?  I presume the App path is under `Program Files`?  If so, then you're not going to have permission to write to that location, or a subfolder, by default. Rather than granting runtime write permissions to there (which most security IT personnel would object to), you should consider configuring your BatFiles folder under a location where you likely do have write permission, for instance `Program Data`.